# Проблемы с подключением к БД (postgresql) в телеграм боте

Tags: python, база-данных, postgresql, telegram, aiogram

**У меня проблемы с подключение PostgreSQL. Прошу вашей помощи.**

[image: Консоль]

[image: Тут создаю подключаю БД]

[image: Создаю БД]

[image: Файл запуска]

Comment: есть мнение что никто не будет переписывать ваш код с скринов что бы воспроизвести проблему

Comment: я бы пошел дальше, нужен репозиторий с requirements.txt чтобы быстро это воспроизвести и помочь